# Improving gaming performance in wine

Tags: wine, performance, playonlinux

When running League of Legends through wine I get about 50fps while I would like to run the game at a stable 60fps with vsync.
Is there any way I can achieve higher framerates, or is my hardware just outdated?

Specs:

GTX 560ti

i5-3570

8GB ddr3 1600mhz ram

Answer (score 1):

Did you take a look at the [Wine App DB entry of League of Legends](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=19141&iTestingId=86428)? There's a section with tips to increase performance.

Otherwise there are very few things you can do:

- use a current proprietary graphics adapter driver,
- try a newer (or sometimes older) Wine version,
- try a different desktop compositor or none at all.

Comment: Also be aware that Wine relies more in CPU than GPU.